# Синглтон через enum для хранения соединения с БД

Tags: java, шаблоны-проектирования

Хочу разобраться в том, как использовать синглтон, реализуемый по рекомендации Джошуа Блоха через enum, для хранения соединения с БД. Я написал такой код:

```
import com.rethinkdb.RethinkDB;
import com.rethinkdb.net.Connection;

public enum Singleton {
    INSTANCE;

    public Connection getConnection() {
        if (connection == null || !connection.isOpen()) {
            connection = RethinkDB.r.connection().connect();
        }
        return connection;
    }

    private Connection connection;
}
```

Задача такова:

- Синглтон хранит соединение с БД
- При обрыве соединения оно должно быть повторно установлено

В моем коде не используется константа INSTANCE, которая является ключевым элементом данного подхода. Эта константа - объект enum'а, существующий в единственном экземпляре, а я использую класс enum'а как классический класс синглтона.

Как можно адаптировать этот подход для написания синглтона, хранящего соединение? В каких ситуациях в реальной разработке применим синглтон через enum?

Comment: Подход жизнеспособен, до тех пор пока вы не захотите это покрыть тестами.

Comment: @Stranger in the Q, тестировщик протестирует. Зачем тратить время на тесты? К тому же я пока что не знаю альтернативу синглтону в ситуации, когда используется некоторый нестандартный драйвер и нужна дополнительная логика работы с соединением.

Comment: Если приложение однопоточное то работать будет, если многопоточное то нет, connection не потокобезопасен.

Comment: верно instance не используется, метод должен юыть не у enum а у объекта instance, каждый элемент  enum может иметь свои поля и методы,

Comment: я написал покрыть тестами а не протестировать, это далеко не одно и то же

Comment: @fox.ontour, как можно сделать, чтобы метод был у объекта instance, а не у enum?